# Linking C program to two libraries

Tags: c, gcc, hdfs, avro

I am having trouble linking my C program to two libraries.
My program reads data from a message queue which contains aggregated logs of our load balanced web servers.

Currently I am already linking my program to Avro library by executing the following command:

```
gcc getData.c -o getData -lavro
```

The program picks data from the message queue and based on the Avro schema, generated avro records in a .avro file and stores it locally.

The business requirement is to write the .avro files directly to HDFS.
For writing to HDFS I tried using the [HDFS C API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/libhdfs.html).

The problem now is that now I need to link my program to two libraries.
When I tried using:

```
gcc getData.c -o getData -lavro -lhdfs
```

I got an error message.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You've stated that you get an error; you've not shown us what the error message is (or messages are). That means we can't begin to guess what the problem actually is.  It might be as simple as 'list the libraries in the reverse order'.  It might be that you need to list more than two libraries: the new `-lhdfs` library may require some other libraries listed after it. There's no evidence of static linking or static libraries being a factor in your problem. Please edit the (first dozen or so) actual error messages into the question.

Comment: Let's guess the error message: "Can't link library due to insuffient information". If this is wrong, update your question please.